# Old version of my app APK for arm64-v8a ABI being distributed on Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

As the title suggests I have an application on the Play Store that appears to being distributed as a much older version of the current release but only for the arm64-v8a ABI. It is quite a large version difference over a long period of time so this is not just me not allowing time for the publish to finish. What's also strange is that I can download my app through the Play Store while authenticated as the developer account attached to the application. I thought this wasn't allowed? It also appears that I can leave my app a review which is very strange.

I believe the cause of this may be related to flashing LineageOS 15.1 on my device earlier today, but I have no way of verifying.

**Additional information:**

- A utility application is showing the architecture of the device as
  aarch64
- Viewing the version through Chrome is displaying version 2.1.9 while
  the Play Store application is displaying/distributing version 2.0.0
- The developer console shows all expected APKs for targeted ABIs
- I'm able to successfully download and install the APK for this
  architecture/device through the developer dashboard and it functions
  as expected
- I'm able to successfully build and deploy the application to the
  device through Android Studio
- Google Play version: 12.1.18-all [0] [PR] 216263519

**Gradle entry for generating version codes per ABI:**

```
ext.abiCodes = [
        // Ignoring mips and armeabi
        'armeabi-v7a': 2,
        'arm64-v8a'  : 3,
        'x86'        : 4,
        'x86_64'     : 5
]

import com.android.build.OutputFile

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def baseAbiVersionCode = project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))

        if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {
            output.versionCodeOverride = baseAbiVersionCode * 10000000 + variant.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

My biggest fear is that I'm borking distribution of certain ABIs but I'm hoping that's not the case since I can download and install the correct APK through the developer console. I'm hoping this is more related to the flash I did today due to the strange issues I'm seeing surrounding the Google Play app.

**What is causing the wrong version of my APK to be distributed for this ABI? I'd be happy to provide additional information. Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Update:

After posting this question, I migrated my gradle to work with the new app bundles and it seems to have fixed the distribution for this architecture. I'm not sure why it resolved the issue because there was still an APK for the architecture listed in the developer console that worked perfectly fine. However, I'm going to leave this question open because I feel that this should have worked with ABI splits. Below is my update gradle configuration:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.masterwok.bitcast"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 50000039
        versionName "2.1.10"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Left blank for brevity..
}
```

Comment: Is it being served for all people with that architecture, or only certain devices? It's possible you bumped up your minSdkVersion or introduced some other limiting factor into your code to prevent it from being installed on certain devices. Google Play will continue to service old, compatible versions of your APK to people who can't install the new one.

Comment: As for the other issues: as long as your app is free, you, as the developer, can download it. You can also review it, if you want (this has been the case for at least 1.5 years and I doubt it's going to be "fixed").

Comment: @TheWanderer Thank you, I was not aware that this was the case for free applications. To my knowledge, the APK is being served to all people with that architecture (play store has it listed as 2572 compatible devices). I have a seperate APK for x86_64, x86, arm64-v8a, and armeabi-v7a. Currently, the minSdkVersion is set to 16 and the targestSdkVersion is set to 27. The device is running Android 8.1.0 (API 27) and is  OnePlus 5 running LineageOS 15.1.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using separate ABIs? If you have a Java-only application, one APK is enough.

Comment: @TheWanderer I'm using seperate APKs to reduce the size of the final APK. For this specific application, producing a single APK supporting all ABIs would result in a very large APK.